# How to store arrays of points (X,Y, color) inside Postgres array

Tags: postgresql, postgis

How to store in Postgres the data where every record in  external data stream has the following structure :
(timestamp, [(x1,y1, color1), (x2,y2, color2), ...])
?

Number of points vary from record to record.

I tried to use PostGIS:

```
    CREATE TABLE AllPoints(
        id serial,
        time  timestamp with time zone,
        points geometry(POINT)[]
    );
```

But I cannot figure out how to capture the 'color' attribute  (which exist for every point)  in PostGIS POINT object.

Another option I considered is: to store the array of points with color as JSON in JSONB column, but in this case I am losing PostGIS SQL functions (e.g. find all points in specified region).

Comment: If you properly normalize this (i.e. not using an array) it's as simple as adding a new column to the table that contains the point

Comment: Number of points is not fixed; for the different timestamps we expect the different number of points, this is why I am using array.

Comment: The number of rows in a table is not fixed either. You do have a classical one-to-many relationship here.

Comment: If the color can be a `double precision`, you could store it as "M dimension" in PostGIS.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, _a_horse_with_no_name suggested to have 2 tables:

T1 (id, timestamp) and 

T2(t1_id, POINT, color) 

where t1_id is the FK to T1(id). 

Looks right to me, I will try it today.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion given by _a_horse_with_no_name works for me.